# how to make static library link against frameworks needed automatically in xcode

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, static-libraries

I have a static library base on MapKit.framework CoreLocation.framework etc.

I want to distribute the static library to other developers, to make it easy, I hope to find a method to eliminate the process of linking against frameworks in developers project.

I know there are some people achieve this.

If you can read chinese, you can refer to

http://dev.umeng.com/releasenote/releasenote_ana_ios.html

简化SDK集成，一句代码集成友盟SDK([MobClick startWithAppkey:]),不再需要手动link framework

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do this as of Xcode 4.5.2.  A static library cannot specify its dynamic library dependencies.  Only a dynamic library can do that.

Comment: can previous version of xcode do this? the 友盟SDK I mention above is a static library